# Show $\log (\log n + 1) \leq \log \log n + \frac{1}{\log (n + 1)}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

How does one show that $\log (\log n + 1) \leq \log \log n + \dfrac{1}{\log (n + 1)}$ for $n \geq 3$?

For context, I saw this inequality in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0008177v2 (formula 3.8).

Comment: $$\log (\log n + 1)=\log\left(\log n\left(1+\frac{1}{\log n} \right) \right)
=\log\log n+\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\log n}\right)$$ 

so for $n \ge 3$ you need to show that

$$\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\log n}\right)\le \frac{1}{\log (n + 1)}$$

Comment: According to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%281%2B1%2Flog%28n%29%29+%3C%3D+1%2Flog%28n%2B1%29), the inequality holds for $n \ge 2$.

Comment: Why are you guys closing this question? It's a genuinely non trivial inequality and interesting question! Because OP didn't show any of their own work? There are plenty of such (open) questions on MSE.

Comment: I agree, the proof of the above inequality doesn't seem to be trivial at all (I don't have time right now to go through your answer but it appears to be the correct approach).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic becausewe soaw no effort from your side.

Comment: Is the LHS $\log(\log(n) + 1)$ or $\log(\log(n+1))$?

Comment: @Cesareo showing effort is just one way [of a few suggested](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to add context to a question.

Comment: @rtybase You can leave a paper as context which is very comfortable. Some effort is needed, such as indicating the paragraph in which the main results are found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's show that

> For $x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$ we have
>   $$\ln(1+x) \leq x-\frac{x^2}{3} \tag{1}$$

Indeed, $f(x)=\ln(1+x)-x + \frac{x^2}{3}$ has first derivative $f'(x)=\frac{2x}{3}+\frac{1}{1+x}-1=\frac{x(2x-1)}{3(x+1)}\leq 0$ when $x\in \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$.
So $f(x)$ is descending on $x\in \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$ or for $0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow f(0)\geq f(x)$ which is $0\geq \ln(1+x)-x + \frac{x^2}{3}$ and the result follows.

This can also be reformulated as, for $x \geq 2$
$$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) \leq \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3x^2} \iff 
\color{blue}{x\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) \leq 1-\frac{1}{3x}} \tag{2}$$

---

I [will also use the fact that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#Inequalities)
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x<e \tag{3}$$

---

Now let's change the original inequality as
$$\log (\log n + 1) \leq \log \log n + \frac{1}{\log (n + 1)}\iff \\
\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\log{n}}\right)\leq \frac{1}{\log(n+1)} \iff \\
\log(n+1)\cdot\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\log{n}}\right)\leq 1 \iff \\
\left(\log{n}+\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\cdot\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\log{n}}\right)\leq 1 \iff $$
$$\left(\log{n}+\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{n}\right)\cdot\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\log{n}}\right)\leq 1 \tag{4}$$

---

And finally
$$\left(\log{n}+\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{n}\right)\cdot\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\log{n}}\right) \overset{(3)}{<} \\
\left(\log{n}+\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\log{n}}\right) = \\
\left(1+\frac{1}{n\log{n}}\right)\cdot \color{red}{\log{n} \cdot\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\log{n}}\right)} \overset{(2)}{<} \\
\left(1+\frac{1}{n\log{n}}\right)\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{3\log{n}}\right)=\\
1-\frac{1}{3n\log^2(n)}-\frac{1}{3\log{n}}+\frac{1}{n\log{n}} < 1$$
since 
$$-\frac{1}{3\log{n}}+\frac{1}{n\log{n}} <0$$
and for $\log{n}>2 \iff n >e^2 > 7$. So $(4)$ is true for $n>7$. Cases $n\in\{3,4,5,6,7\}$ can be validated manually or with a computer program.

Comment: Nice work. $\log\left(1+\frac 1n\right)<\frac 1n$ also follows from the well-known inequality $\log(1+t)<t$ for $t\ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to prove that

$\min\left(\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\log n}\right)\right) \leq \max \left(\frac{1}{\log n+1}\right)$,

which can easily be done by differentiating both expressions and equating them to $0$.

But in this case, both derivatives don't come out to be $0$ at any point. So just finding their tendency value as $n$ tends to the extreme values of the domain, should give you their respective extrema.