# Proving that $ \prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\left(1+\frac{1}{k^{3}}\right)}<\mathrm{e} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, products

How would you prove that $$ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ \prod_{k=1}^{n}{\left(1+\frac{1}{k^{3}}\right)}<\mathrm{e} $$

Wolfram|Alpha says its limit would be exactly $ \frac{\cosh{\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{2}\right)}}{\pi} $, but I think it might be nicer to solve the problem without trying to compute the infinite product. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Equivalently, you want
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \log \left( 1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right) < 1 $$
Now $\log(1+t) < t$, but $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/k^3 = \zeta(3) > 1$, so that doesn't quite
do it.  However, leave the $k=1$ term as $\log(2)$ and it does work:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{k^3}\right) \le \log(2) + \zeta(3) - 1 \approx 0.895204084$$

Or if you don't want to have to evaluate $\zeta(3)$ numerically, use
$$ \zeta(3) - 1 = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^3} \le \int_{3/2}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^3} = \frac{2}{9} $$
where by Jensen's inequality and convexity of $1/x^3$, 
$$\dfrac{1}{k^3} \le \int_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2} \dfrac{dx}{x^3}$$
Then our bound is
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \log \left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right) \le \log(2) + \frac{2}{9}
\approx 0.9153694028 $$

Comment: If you render $\log 2 =\int_1^2(dx/x)$, you can easily bound it. The convex function $f(x)=1/x$ lies below $g(x)=(3-x)/2$ which intersects $f$ at $1$ and $2$.  Then the logarithm is less than $\int_1^2g(x)dx=3/4<(1-2/9)$.

Answer (score 2):

With AM>GM render for all $k\ge 2$:

$1+\dfrac{1}{k^3}<\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\dfrac{1}{k^3}}{1-\dfrac{1}{k^3}}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{k^3+1}{k^3-1}}$

We then have

$\prod_{k=2}^\infty\sqrt{\dfrac{k^3+1}{k^3-1}}=\prod_{k=2}^\infty\sqrt{\dfrac{(k+1)((k-1)^2+(k-1)+1)}{(k-1)(k^2+k+1)}}\overset{telescopes}{=}\sqrt{3/2}$

So multiplying in the $k=1$ term which equals $2$:

$\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1+\dfrac{1}{k^3})<2\prod_{k=2}^\infty\sqrt{\dfrac{k^3+1}{k^3-1}}=\sqrt{6}$

To four significant digits $\sqrt6=2.449$ and the exact value quoted by the OP $=2.428$.

It remains to prove that $e>\sqrt6$.  Here we simply use the series $e=1+(1/1!)+(1/2!)+...$ (all positive terms) $>5/2>\sqrt6$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [the fact that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3505564/show-log-log-n-1-leq-log-log-n-frac1-log-n-1/3509326#3509326)
$$\ln(1+x)\leq x-\frac{x^2}{3}, x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$$
to conclude 
$$\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right)\leq2\prod\limits_{k=2}^n e^{\frac{1}{k^3}-\frac{1}{3k^6}}=
2\cdot e^{\sum\limits_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{k^3}-\frac{1}{3k^6}\right)}$$
[but](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fx%5E3%20-%201%2F%283x%5E6%29)
$$\sum\limits_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{k^3}-\frac{1}{3k^6}\right)=
\frac{23}{192}+\sum\limits_{k=3}^n\left(\frac{1}{k^3}-\frac{1}{3k^6}\right)\leq \\
\frac{23}{192}+\int\limits_{2}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{3x^6}\right)dx=
\frac{23}{192}+\frac{59}{480}-\frac{15 n^3-2}{30 n^5}$$
thus
$$\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right)<2\cdot e^{\frac{23}{192}+\frac{59}{480}}=\color{red}{2}\cdot e^{\frac{233}{960}}< e^{\color{red}{\frac{3}{4}}+\frac{233}{960}}=e^{\frac{953}{960}}<e$$